# GTM IOs not track some events

Tags: ios, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I follow the official example from GTM-IOs. To sample if works or not; i do a stupid method, resumed in:

TAGDataLayer *dataLayer = tagManager.dataLayer;

```
id trac = [[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker];

[trac push:@{@"event": @"openScreen", @"screenName": @"Home Screen"}];
[trac send:@{@"event": @"openScreen", @"screenName": @"Home Screen"}];
[dataLayer push:@{@"event": @"openScreen", @"screenName": @"Home Screen"}];
[tagManager dispatch];
```

My Console LOG shows me these; but nothing recieved:

2015-06-23 17:57:56.907 uterque[15487:184150] GTM: Verbose: GoogleAnalytics 3.12 -[GAIRequestBuilder requestPostUrl:payload:compression:] (GAIRequestBuilder.m:167): building URLRequest for https://ssl.google-analytics.com/batch
2015-06-23 17:57:56.907 uterque[15487:184150] GTM: Verbose: GoogleAnalytics 3.12 -[GAIBatchingDispatcher dispatchWithCompletionHandler:] (GAIBatchingDispatcher.m:632): Sending hit(s) POST: https://ssl.google-analytics.com/batch
2015-06-23 17:57:57.147 uterque[15487:184093] GTM: Info: GoogleAnalytics 3.12 -[GAIBatchingDispatcher didSendHits:response:data:error:] (GAIBatchingDispatcher.m:226): Hit(s) dispatched: HTTP status 200
2015-06-23 17:57:57.147 uterque[15487:184150] GTM: Info: GoogleAnalytics 3.12 -[GAIBatchingDispatcher deleteHits:] (GAIBatchingDispatcher.m:529): hit(s) Successfully deleted
2015-06-23 17:57:57.148 uterque[15487:184150] GTM: Info: GoogleAnalytics 3.12 -[GAIBatchingDispatcher didSendHits:] (GAIBatchingDispatcher.m:237): 2 hit(s) sent